# Copy/Paste a column with a function

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy/paste a column with a function.

```
function myfunction3() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
var sheetRaw = ss.getSheetByName("RAW DATA");
var sheetRawLastRow = sheetRaw.getLastRow();
var sheetRawFourthColumn = sheetRaw.getRange(2,4,sheetRawLastRow,1).getValues(); //the part of the column that I want to copy/paste
var exDateList = [] //creating the array that I want to paste

for (var i = 0; i < sheetRawFourthColumn.length; i++ ) { //creating a loop to copy each element of the column to the new array that I've created

exDateList[i] = sheetRawFourthColumn[i]

//trying to monitor what is happening
console.log[i]; 
console.log(sheetRawFourthColumn.length);
console.log(exDateList[i]);

return(exDateList)

}

}
```

For a reason that I don't understand, I'm only getting the first element of the column. Also, console.log(i) is not displaying

Comment: About `For a reason that I don't understand, I'm only getting the first element of the column. Also, console.log(i) is not displaying`, in your script, `exDateList` is returned at the first loop by `return(exDateList)` in the for-loop. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. But, I cannot understand your expected result from your question because of my poor English skill. So, I cannot propose a modified script you expect. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the details of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. Indeed, with moving the return method outside the loop, it's working as expected. So, it seems return method stop the function. I don't know if it's a normal behaviour?

I still don't understand why console.log doesn't display the current number iteration i ?

Comment: Hmm. Should `console.log[i];` be `console.log(i);`? Did you check the Executions log to see when the script failed.